# Unable to connect to SQL Server with Windows Authentication in a Python script on a MAC

Tags: python, sql-server, macos

I am trying to run a phyton script on my Mac (OS Sierra) to connect to SQL Server (2016) using my login which is a Windows AD authentication but can't seem to get it to work. It throwing an Image not found error message. However, the pytds and pyodbc module both work with another login that uses Sql Server authentication.

I am unable to even trace where the disconnect is. Can someone please advice?

Comment: Lets see your code you wrote.  For anonymity, you can replace your server strings and user/pw strings with dummy variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this connection string:

```
conn= pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={SQL 
Server};Server=yourServer;Database=yourDatabase;Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

replace yourServer and yourDatabase